# Calculating Convex Hull based on attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, fields-attributes, grouping, convex-hull

I have a layer with lots of (spatially grouped) lines - lines belonging to a group share the same value in a field.
I would like to create convex hulls around each of these groups using QGIS 3.8.

I learned that Vector Geometry->Convex hull is not attribute specific and the batch functionality works with a set of layers, not specific on attributes.

I tried the model builder, but I'm struggling - I would need to first create a set of objects grouped by that attribute (in SQL it would be something like `GROUP BY`), and then something like a "do convex hull for each in set".

Or create a number of new layers based on the attribute and use a convex hull in batch mode? This would be ~100 new layers - could this be handled with QGIS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is another Convex Hull function in the "Vector geometry" -" "Minimum bounding geometry" tool. That one allows you to specify a field by with the geometries should be grouped.

Comment: I didn't know this tool. It solves my problem and is able to not only produce convex hull but also bounding box etc.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, since you are referencing SQL yourself, why not use the natively supported SpatiaLite dialect?

Get familiar with *Virtual Layers* and the *DB Manager* if not already, and run sth. like

```sql
SELECT <that_attribute>,
       ST_ConcaveHull(ST_Collect(geometry)) AS geometry
FROM   <layer_name>
GROUP BY
       <that_attribute>
;
```

Comment: Caveat and benefit: Using this approach the hulls are going to be recalculated on each map interaction.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I don't see a caveat; you have the ultimate flexibility of spatial SQL: alter output with a simple change of functions or their parameters, no limit to what attributes/values you group by, and if you want persistent results (and only then, in contrast to the use of the built-in tools), just export to e.g. file

Comment: It can become very slow. The user might not be aware that it is not a one-time operation but constantly recalculated. If their data is static, it is not really necessary. Don't get me wrong, this approach is awesome IF you know the caveats.

Comment: @bugmenot123 yeah I might be biased by the ways I do things ,) good to point that out!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a convex hull based on an attribute using QGIS expressions with "Geometry Generator" or "Geometry by Expression" (see here for [details about both options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). Use this expression:

```
convex_hull(collect($geometry, group_by:="attribute_name"))
```